# adding dynamic checkboxes to android when i click a button

Tags: android, dynamic, checkbox, view

i just started to develop a simple checklist app, the idea is that i have an EditText, and a button. When i enter the text and hit the "add" button i want it to make a checklist.
i have managed to get the app to display a check-box with the text i enter, the only problem is that i can't find a way to get new check-box'es onto the screen.

And the most annoying thing is that i know why it is doing this, i have declared just one  checkbox named "cb", and of course when i hit enter it will always assign new values to "cb".

would be very thankful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

```
package com.pzayx.shoppinglist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;



 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int i = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //setContentView(R.layout.activity_dynamic_views);
    /*
     * Adds scrollview inside a linearlayout, 
             *setting up a edittext, a add button and a checkbox
     */
    final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
    ScrollView scrl = new ScrollView(this);
    final LinearLayout lil = new LinearLayout(this);
     lil.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     scrl.addView(lil);
     final EditText EDIT_TEXT = new EditText(this);
     EDIT_TEXT.setText("");
     lil.addView(EDIT_TEXT);
     Button btn = new Button(this);
     btn.setText("Add");
     lil.addView(btn);

     btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
            String text = EDIT_TEXT.getText().toString();
            EDIT_TEXT.setText("");
            cb.setId(i);
            cb.setText(text);
            text = null;
            lil.addView(cb);
            i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

     });
     this.setContentView(scrl);


    }
public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                cb.setText("I'm dynamic!");
                lil.addView(cb);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, i had to insert;
cb.setid(i);
and then it inserted more checkboxes, now i got something to work with !